# align matSuffix content with a text inside mat-form-field input

Tags: angular, input, angular-material

I have a mat-form-field with `<span></span>` as a `matSuffix`

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input matInput
    placeholder="Details"
    name="details"
    required />
  <span matSuffix></span>
</mat-form-field>
```

The problem that emigi does not align with a text

[image]

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: if you use `<mat-icon>` you will not going to face any problem, if you use any custom icon add this styles `.mat-form-field-flex{ align-items: center }` make sure to apply this styles to only custom icon input. Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 8):

Use a DIV and try adjusting the position of the icon to compensate for the discrepancy between the default font size 16px and the size of a standard mat-icon suffix 24px:

```
<div matSuffix style="position: relative; bottom: 8px;"></div>
```

Comment: i ended up doing same

Comment: wouldn't it be better to alter the font-size of the icon then?

Answer (score 1):

Just override `mat-form-field-infix` and `mat-form-field-suffix` class as below

```
.mat-form-field-infix {
   top: 0em !important;
}      
.mat-form-field-suffix {
   top: 0em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by overriding the material class. i.e. `:host /deep/ .mat-form-field-suffix { top: 0; }`